Ngrok response status
When I response with status 200 ngrok does not dislpay it,
but if I response with ex. 201 it does.
I am calling webhook endpoint, which runs some time.
Why?
14:58:44.302 CESTPOST /api/WebhookHandler
14:52:53.344 CESTPOST /api/WebhookHandler
14:47:52.143 CESTPOST /api/WebhookHandler       201 Created
14:47:06.367 CESTPOST /api/WebhookHandler
Thank you, Matjaz

You can try https://pinggy.io . One command will start the tunnel ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:8080 -L4300:localhost:4300 qr@a.pinggy.io (Change port 8080). Then use the debugger at http://localhost:4300
